# Geopandas in Raspberry pi 4 ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, geopandas, raspberry-pi4

Imposible to install geopandas in raspberry pi 4 8gb with ubuntu 20.10.

I install Miniforge3. I did `conda instal geopandas` in a empty enviaroment.

and always says.

````
(test_env) carberry@rasp:~/ir/DataTown$ conda install geopandas

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                            

UnsatisfiableError: 

(test_env) carberry@rasp:~/ir/DataTown$ ```
````

Comment: There are likely no builds for ARM suitable for raspberry pi for some of GeoPandas C dependencies (shapely, fiona, pyproj).

Comment: Is impossible to run geopandas, and what is the alternative to read a geojson, transform to dataframe, filter and transform again to a geojson???